# MySQL Partitioning Multiple Tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm using MySQL MyISAM and I have 7 tables in my database linked by a primary key called `ID`. I want to `PARTITION` the data on one of these tables by its timestamp. When I want to delete a partition, I'd like to delete all records on the other tables with the same `ID` as the ones I deleted from the partition.

Can this be done at a similar speed as dropping a partition? I don't particularly want to go to each table and search for the right `ID` to delete as it would defeat the purpose of partitioning in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot achieve what you want as you stated it.

Are all the tables the same size?  Or perhaps the other tables are "normalization" tables?  In that case, just leave the data there?

Please elaborate on what kind of data you have and the relationships (1:1, 1:many, etc) between the tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can create triggers for those tables:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html